# IIS Launch Condition In Web Setup Project

Tags: asp.net, installation

I'm developing Web Setup for my .NET 2.0 web application with VS 2005, and it has some prerequisites (.NET 2.0, Sql Server Express,and Windows Installer). 
My question is :how to check IIS launch condition before prerequisites?

Answer (score 4):

it work for me in VS2010.

in solution explorer, right click on `Setup` project. select `View`->`Launch Condition`.

in `Search Target machine`.

Add registry Search for Major version:

```
Name: Search for IIS Major Version  
Property: IISMAJORVERSION  
RegKey: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters  
root: vsdrrHKLM  
Value: MajorVersion
```

Add Registry Search for Minor version:

```
Name: Search for IIS Minor Version  
Property: IISMINORVERSION   
RegKey: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters  
root: vsdrrHKLM  
Value: MinorVersion
```

in Launch Conditions Add new Item with this value:

```
name: IIS Condition  
Condition: (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6"  
Message: This program need to IIS version 5.1 or above
```