# IIS Launch Condition in WebSetupProject fails to detect IIS 10 on Win10

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis

Our WebSetupProjects (created in VisualStudio 2010) fail to properly detect version of IIS on Win10.

My thought is that it has to do with the way how this condition is spelled out - note the double-quotes:

```
     (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6"
```

so even though registry check in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters` for `MajorVersion` and `MinorVersion` returns *dword-integer* values, they are being coerced into *string* representation, therefore resulting in "10" being *less* than "5" or "6" - thus failing the check.

I haven't tried removing double-quotes yet, but am afraid they may be there for a reason (i.e. without them the check won't work properly).  Still, will attempt this once i get a chance, and will report on it.

In the meantime, has anyone encountered the same scenario and found how to solve it?

Comment: See if this is helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152506/iis-launch-condition-in-web-setup-project

Comment: Saw it already, doesn't help - that's an old question for VS 2005, targeting older IIS versions.  The answer is directly from VS 2010 WebSetupProject, that's what i'm starting with (see above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great idea, @MartinMisol!  Should've thought of it myself :).  But seems unnecessary, at least so far.

As initially indicated, I tried removing double-quotes from around the numbers in the condition string (leaving pound-signs in place):

```
        (IISMAJORVERSION >= #5 AND IISMINORVERSION >= #1) OR IISMAJORVERSION >= #6
```

That satisfied the .msi package (prepared by VisualStudio 2010) on Windows 10 Professional Edition.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no nice way to do it. You could change the condition like this:
 `((IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR IISMAJORVERSION >= "#6") OR IISMAJORVERSION = "#10"`

The problem is that you would have to update the condition with every new release of Windows.

Maybe you should consider migrating your setup projects to [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/), since setup projects are no longer supported by Microsoft. Using WIX you can implement a custom action to programatically check for the required version of IIS, reading it from the registry and casting it to an integer before comparing.